# Samba AD - Member server necessary?

Tags: active-directory, network-share, samba4

For a small windows network (5 users with their own machines) I set up an AD DC using Samba 4 on Arch Linux on a HP Microserver.

Those users have files they will need to access from a central location, namely concurrent access to a file db and some shared PDFs. Traffic will be moderate, the server should easily be able to handle the work.

The official documentation, however, strongly recommends setting up a member server for file serving purposes.

From https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setup_a_Samba_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller:

> The Samba team do not recommend using the Domain Controller as a file
>   server, the recommendation is to run a separate Member Server as file
>   server

- Is this really necessary in my case?

  - If yes, is there a strong case against a containerized (LXC) Samba system on the same host?
  - If no, can you hint me to how to set up both on the same host? What is needed in the share definition?

Comment: Can you please link to the bit of the documentation recommending a member server? Not sure what the reason for the member server would be. If it was for performance reasons I would say it's definitely not necessary for such a small number of clients. Also, setting up a member server on the same physical machine using virtualization wouldn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I have edited my question to include the documentation link. It doesn't really offer good reasons for a separate member server that's why I asked here. Is there anything I have to specially consider when adding a share definition to my smb.conf on the DC?

Comment: The source page seems to have some reasoning added-in to back up the member server recommendation.

Especially given your use of containers, and given the limitations aren't performance-related, piit79's recommendation above - yes, run a separate member server on the same physical - sounds like a great idea and probably the best answer we'll see. 

Please consider designating piit79's response as an answer.